# table get the cell from the row

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have one table with 3 rows and 3 columns. Now I want to add 2 row's 2nd columns cell's control. That means whether that is text or combox in the cell. How do I get the 2nd row's 2nd column  and remove the compoenent dynamically in SWT JFace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use a TableViewer?

The SWT-way of getting to the item is indexed first by row, than by column.
Getting the text of the third column in the second row is done like this:

```
table.getItem(1).getText(2);
```

To display custom-controls, like a combobox you will have to either paint it manually or use SWT's [TableEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/TableEditor.html).

Also check out this tutorial: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Table-viewer/table_viewer.html

Comment: Ok.Thanks a lot!!!. But can that control be removed from the cell of 2nd row's 2nd column?

Comment: Yes. Just dispose() the TableEditor.